# Xcode 6 how to rename copied target

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I know that this is not a new question, but I have tried many solution like edit Xcode project file manually or recreating new scheme for target after renaming it.

Can somebody help me with this question how copy target in right way and then rename it.

Right now I just rename scheme and it is displayed as is. But when Xcode is running app, under progress indicator it says: Running ProjectName-copy. But I have renamed target but seems product names or some build settings still has "...-copy" in the name.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

1. Duplicate a target.
2. Double click the copy of target and change its name to whatever you want.
3. 'New target -> Build Settings -> Packaging -> Product Name', change it to the name you want.
4. Product (Menu item) > Schemes > Manage Schemes, then click the '+' button, select the new target and click 'OK' button.

All done.

PS:
After Duplicating the target, Xcode make a new Info.plist file named 'xxx copy-Info.plist' in the root path of project. If you want to change its name and path, after doing this, you should go to 'New target -> Build Settings -> Packaging -> Info.plist file' and change the value to the path of new file.

Comment: xcode 7, can`t find original target to duplicate it :( where is it?

Comment: This all look good, but for IB files, the Module parameter does not get changed to "current" automatically, so you see run time crashes in loading. How to get rid of that?

Comment: in 4th step instead of pressing '+' button, you can just select new target and press Enter, it allows you to change name of scheme. ( tested on Xcode Version 8.2.1 (8C1002) )

Answer (score 35):

Press on the target name in xcode ( in the same place where you want to select the sim/device type) and select "Manage Schemes...". Highlight the scheme with the copy inside name and press enter on keyboard. You can rename it there.

Comment: Real answer to make it change and not say "targetname copy"

Comment: Well hidden feature.

Answer (score 4):

To copy a target, click on your project, and go to the project inspector tab that looks like this:

Project:
SomeName

Targets:
SomeName

right click on a target, and select duplicate, then double-click slowly on the new target, or select the new target and hit enter, and just put the new name in!

To change running targets, to the top left of your xcode you will see this:

(start button)    (stop Button)      (target name and device)
[|>]              [[]]               [/\ TargetName > TargetDevice]

click the target name, next to the little compass (mathematical compass, not navigational) and select your desired target from the dropdown.

Hope I helped, Matroskin.

Comment: Renaming of the target does not rename it in the schemes or in the product. It just rename target in the project setting but not affect to the another file name.

So for example if by the default Xcode creates the target name, scheme name and product name the same like project name, but if we duplicate target and rename it, so this action just renames target not product name and scheme name.

Comment: I did a combination of renaming target in `Project and Targets list` and deleting & creating new scheme in `Manage Schemes`.

Comment: How about a screenshot or two to make sense of things